# Interpolating RGB color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm wrestling with how to interpolate a color, given a `start_time` and `end_time`, `start_color` and `end_color`. For simplicity, here is an example of how I'm thinking of doing it with just the red component:

```
start_time = 0
end_time = 1
start_color = F //base 16 ftw
end_color = 0
```

I can see how at time .5, `red_out` should be 8. This would be midway through fading from bright red to black.

So is it `time_elapsed * start_color`? But then what if it's fading the other way, from black to bright red? This is where I get confused.

Comment: Good stuff, ty all.


var red_out = time_alive * ( pArray[i].pEndColorRed - pArray[i].pStartColorRed ) / ( now - pArray[i].pStarttime ).toString(16);

Comment: ugh and this is officially the ugliest line of code Ive everwrote lol
<br><br>

var red_out =
                (Math.abs(parseInt((time_alive * (pArray[i].pEndColorRed - pArray[i].pStartColorRed) / ( pArray[i].pLifespan ))))).toString(16);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each color component you have to use the following formula (nothing magical):

```
color = time_elapsed * (end_color - start_color) / (end_time - star_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way seems simple enough, if you think that at time `t` (where t ranges from 0 to 1), the value of the channel is:

```
start + t * (end - start)
```

This way, if the end value is *less than* the start value (as in the red -> black case), the `end - start` clause is negative, so as time increases the value *decreases* as needed.

It's also to see that in the edge cases,

```
t = 0   =>   start + 0 = start
t = 1   =>   start + (end - start) = end
```

as required.

Edit: The nice thing about this representation is that it makes it clear how to modify the rate of decay as well.  So long as the value for `t` starts off at 0 and eventually hits 1, it doesn't necessarily have to be modified linearly.  For instance, if you wanted the interpolation to start slowly and accelerate towards the end you could use t<sup>2</sup> instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
interpolated_color_component = (current_time - start_time) / (end_time - start_time) * (end_color_component - start_color_component) + start_color_component
```